# Take a user back to an app after they activate a device setting as seen in the CyanogenMod installer

Tags: java, android, settings, user-experience

The question is how can an app automatically take a user back into the application from the device settings menu when a particular setting is activated?

I recently read a paragraph from [an article](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/11/android-roms-the-easy-way-testing-the-new-cyanogenmod-installer/) about the Cyanogenmod installer and its install process where the user is taken from the app to the developer options settings menu and as soon as they select 'USB debugging enabled' they are whisked back to the application. I've tested it on my Nexus 4 running 4.3 and it works as described. Here's the paragraph and an image:

> A few Android apps have "settings walkthroughs" like this, and
> normally they are pretty confusing. Usually the app shows you
> instructions, kicks you out to the settings, and requires you to hit
> "back" to return to the app. If the user forgets this or only skims
> the instructions, they're lost in the device settings.
>
> The CyanogenMod Installer has a neat trick though: as soon as you
> check ADB debugging, the app immediately takes the user back over,
> pulls you from the Settings screen, and pushes everything to the next
> step. Other than checking the box for you (which isn't possible), it
> couldn't be any easier.

[image]

I'd like to be able to replicate this functionality but have no idea how to go about it. Googling has produced nothing of note either. It just seems like it would be a great user experience to have this happen automatically rather than relying on the user to know to press the back button.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the device Settings menu, then there is no way you can achieve this effect, cause you have no way to change other app's default behavior.

Comment: I was talking about device settings, tried to make it more clear. The paragraph from the Arstechnica article seems to disagree with you unless I'm reading it incorrectly.

Comment: @Peanut, The only way it works that I can think of is some customized version of the Settings which allows this kind of behavior. Haven't seen this in action, but it would be interesting to know that it's possible.

Comment: I've just downloaded and tested it and it definitely works. I'm running stock 4.3 on a Nexus 4 so no custom settings. It seems like a great user experience feature, I'm surprised I couldn't find anything about it.